# How to rewrite recursive procedure (repeated f n) as an iterative process using Racket?

Tags: iteration, scheme, racket

This is what I have for recursive procedure `(repeated f n)` that applies the function `f` `n` times to an argument:

```
(define (repeated f count)
  (if (= count 1)
      f 
      (lambda (x)
        (f ((repeated f (- count 1)) x)))))
```

E.g. `((repeated sqr 3) 2)` returns 256, i.e. `(sqr(sqr(sqr 2)))`.

But I have no idea how to implement `repeated` as an iterative process using Racket. Any advice is much obliged.

Answer (score 3):

A typical solution for converting a recursive process to an iterative process is to enlist the aid of an accumulator.

Any way you slice it, `repeated` will have to return a procedure. One solution would use a named `let` inside the returned procedure that iterates `n` times, keeping track of the results in an accumulator. Here is a version of `repeated` that returns a unary procedure; note that there is no input validation here, so calls like `((repeated f 0) 'arg)` will lead to trouble.

```
(define (repeated f n)
  (lambda (x)
    (let iter ((n n)
               (acc x))
      (if (= n 1) (f acc)
          (iter (- n 1)
                (f acc))))))
```

Named `let` expressions are very handy for things like this, but you could also define a helper procedure to do the same thing. I will leave that solution as an exercise for OP.

```racket
scratch.rkt> ((repeated sqr 3) 2)
256
scratch.rkt> ((repeated add1 8) 6)
14
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using [`for/fold`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#(form._((lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt)._for%2Ffold))) makes a cleaner solution

```
(define ((repeated f n) x)
  (for/fold ([acc x]) ([i (in-range n)]) (f acc)))
```

Using it:

```
> ((repeated sqr 3) 2)
256
> ((repeated add1 8) 6)
14
```

Comment: I would suggest `[_ (in-range n)]` instead of binding unused `i`

Comment: @Thankyou The clause you suggested binds (shadows) `_` instead. `for` et al don't interpret `_` as "don't create a binding" like `match` does. I recommend against shadowing special identifiers like `_` and `else`; it can lead to strange problems. I tend to use underscore-prefixed variable names like `_i` for unused bindings in cases like this.

Comment: Ryan thanks for the note. I appreciate the added detail.